# listitem - Remove - dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have created the list based on the AJAX result. Basically dynamically add the items into the list. But In the second time ajax calling,the list item append to the previous items. I want to reload the list newly. It should contains results of second ajax calling.

I want to remove the all the list items alone.Not a list from the page.

Any one help me.

Code for dynamically add the list value:

```
var parent = document.getElementById('listview');
var listItem = document.createElement('li');
listItem.setAttribute('id','listitem_'+i);
listItem.innerHTML = "one";
parent.appendChild(listItem);
$(parent).listview("refresh");
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$('#listview').children().remove('li');
```

this should do the trick to clear the list.

P.S.
If you intend to use jQuery, then use it.

Comment: Why would one use this method over $('#listview').empty();

Comment: because **#listview** may contain elements that are not **li** and he doesn't want to remove them

Answer (score 14):

If you want to remove everything, then why not use jQuery to do so?

```
$('#listview').empty();
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help you create a iphone like swipe delete. This is in reference to http://forum.jquery.com/topic/adding-an-iphone-style-swipe-to-delete-button-to-a-listview

```
EXERCISEDESCRIPTION.swipeDelete = function(exerciseSetsListview, callback) {

    var listViewJq = '#'+exerciseSetsListview;
    $(listViewJq).children().each(function(){
        var child = $(this);
        var childId = child.attr('id');
        var splitId = childId.split("_");
        var childIdVar = '#'+childId;
        var childIdBtnVar = splitId[0]+'_button_'+splitId[1];
        var childIdBtnVarJq = '#'+childIdBtnVar;

        $(childIdVar).bind('swiperight', function() {
              $(childIdVar).prepend('<a href="#" id="'+childIdBtnVar+'" class="aSwipeBtn" data-theme="b" data-inline="true" data-role="button">Delete</a>');
              $(childIdBtnVarJq).button();
              $(childIdVar).unbind('swiperight');
              $(childIdBtnVarJq).bind('click tap', function() { 
                  $(childIdVar).remove();
                  var splitButtonId = childIdBtnVarJq.split("_");
                  callback(splitButtonId[2]);
              });
            });         

    });

};
```

usage:

```
EXERCISEDESCRIPTION.swipeDelete('exerciseSetsListview',
    function(e) {
        EXERCISEDESCRIPTION.setsObj.splice(e,1);
        EXERCISEDESCRIPTION.repopulateSets();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you're question , you're trying to empty the listview before you add new entryes . You can do this in :

```
var parent = document.getElementById('listview');

//remove all childs here , or easyer with html()
parent.html('');

var listItem = document.createElement('li');
listItem.setAttribute('id','listitem_'+i);
listItem.innerHTML = "one";
parent.appendChild(listItem);
$(parent).listview("refresh");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeAllOptions(selectbox){
   var i;
   for(i=selectbox.options.length-1;i>=0;i--){
       selectbox.remove(i);
   }
}
```